# Node Error: resolve-url-loader: CSS error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-sass, resolve-url-loader

I am trying to run a react project as dev server on my surface, and if gives me the error shown below and in the title. When I am running the same config on my pc I am not having this problem. (I tried creating the same conditions, but it just wont work).

Error:

```
./src/assets/scss/black-dashboard-pro-react.scss?v=1.0.0 (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/assets/scss/black-dashboard-pro-react.scss?v=1.0.0)
Error: resolve-url-loader: CSS error
  source-map information is not available at url() declaration (found orphan CR, try removeCR option)
```

Complete error from Browser Console: (Chrome)

```
Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/Users/Max-T/Documents/Sources/StaffMangerV2/Oauth2Manager-Web/src/assets/scss/black-dashboard-pro-react.scss. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
(anonymous) @ index.js:1679
s @ index.js:499
(anonymous) @ index.js:479
e.<computed> @ index.js:536
S @ index.js:1517
i @ index.js:1534
(anonymous) @ index.js:1541
(anonymous) @ index.js:1530
(anonymous) @ index.js:1699
(anonymous) @ index.js:1673
s @ index.js:499
(anonymous) @ index.js:479
e.<computed> @ index.js:536
S @ index.js:1517
i @ index.js:1534
(anonymous) @ index.js:1541
(anonymous) @ index.js:1530
q @ index.js:1726
I @ index.js:1658
G @ index.js:1817
(anonymous) @ index.js:1831
(anonymous) @ index.js:1848
(anonymous) @ index.js:1332
error (async)
u @ index.js:1334
K @ index.js:1847
ce @ index.js:1951
./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js @ webpackHotDevClient.js:38
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:785
fn @ bootstrap:150
0 @ store.js:18
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:785
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1
index.js:1679 Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/Users/Max-T/Documents/Sources/StaffMangerV2/Oauth2Manager-Web/node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
(anonymous) @ index.js:1679
s @ index.js:499
(anonymous) @ index.js:479
e.<computed> @ index.js:536
S @ index.js:1517
i @ index.js:1534
(anonymous) @ index.js:1541
(anonymous) @ index.js:1530
(anonymous) @ index.js:1699
(anonymous) @ index.js:1673
s @ index.js:499
(anonymous) @ index.js:479
e.<computed> @ index.js:536
S @ index.js:1517
i @ index.js:1534
(anonymous) @ index.js:1541
(anonymous) @ index.js:1530
q @ index.js:1726
I @ index.js:1658
G @ index.js:1817
(anonymous) @ index.js:1831
(anonymous) @ index.js:1848
(anonymous) @ index.js:1332
error (async)
u @ index.js:1334
K @ index.js:1847
ce @ index.js:1951
./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js @ webpackHotDevClient.js:38
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:785
fn @ bootstrap:150
0 @ store.js:18
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:785
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1
main.chunk.js:10 Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js):
Error: resolve-url-loader: CSS error
  source-map information is not available at url() declaration (found orphan CR, try removeCR option)
  at file://C:\Users\Max-T\Documents\Sources\StaffMangerV2\Oauth2Manager-Web\src\assets\scss\black-dashboard-pro-react.scss:13239:3
    at encodeError (C:\Users\Max-T\Documents\Sources\StaffMangerV2\Oauth2Manager-Web\node_modules\resolve-url-loader\index.js:219:12)
    at onFailure (C:\Users\Max-T\Documents\Sources\StaffMangerV2\Oauth2Manager-Web\node_modules\resolve-url-loader\index.js:176:14)
    at Object../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js?!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js?!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?!./src/assets/scss/black-dashboard-pro-react.scss?v=1.0.0 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:10:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:786:30)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151:20)
    at Object../src/assets/scss/black-dashboard-pro-react.scss?v=1.0.0 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:744:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:786:30)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151:20)
    at Module../src/index.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:9220:109)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:786:30)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151:20)
    at Object.0 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:9988:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:786:30)
    at checkDeferredModules (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46:23)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33:19)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:85
./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js?!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js?!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?!./src/assets/scss/black-dashboard-pro-react.scss?v=1.0.0 @ main.chunk.js:10
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:785
fn @ bootstrap:150
./src/assets/scss/black-dashboard-pro-react.scss?v=1.0.0 @ black-dashboard-pro-react.scss?v=1.0.0:1
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:785
fn @ bootstrap:150
./src/index.js @ index.css?e32c:37
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:785
fn @ bootstrap:150
0 @ store.js:18
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:785
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1
index.js:1375 ./src/assets/scss/black-dashboard-pro-react.scss?v=1.0.0 (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/assets/scss/black-dashboard-pro-react.scss?v=1.0.0)
Error: resolve-url-loader: CSS error
  source-map information is not available at url() declaration (found orphan CR, try removeCR option)
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I had this same error. To fix this, I had to navigate to

> node_modules/resolve-url-loader

open

> index.js

and under `var options` change `removeCR` from "false" to "true".

Comment: haven't worked on the project in some time I will try that tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you, just had the same issue and this worked for me.

Comment: can this be configured in angular.js or elsewhere. It feels silly for every developer to change that

Comment: I believe yes, you can add a rule in your webpack.config.js file as follows to enable removeCR. `loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
  options: {
    removeCR: true
  },`

Comment: Also, I am sorry since I don't have that project anymore can't test and confirm this, but if that works for you please post your update.

Comment: This may be sufficient for local development, but this is not acceptable for production (or at all). The `package.json` will create the `node_modules` directory automatically and install the modules from their source, so unless you fork the repo and make this change, i wouldn't recommend changing module files directly.

Comment: I agree with @halshing  we cannot modify manually in production.

Comment: I don't think there should be an issue with that in production, these are the internal loader configurations for webpack and dev dependencies are never included in your production build, so logically if it works in development, the same should work in production. I've not had any such issues in my project, so if someone does, please update.

Comment: Thanks, that also worked for my error `Error: resolve-url-loader: CSS error
   Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`

Comment: Can be solved that by   changing url(..) to new URL(...) inside scss files. Webpack 5 expects new URL(...) declaration

Comment: It didn't work for me but It worked mysteriously after yarn upgrade.

Answer (score 6):

Another option would be to configure the IDE or Editor for the End of Line Sequence type, change from CRLF to LF ... They are only alternatives ... try it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

well, the solution must be related to some package configuration or something. But I want to share the solution that I applied:

```
@import "variables";
@import "colored-balls";
@import "glowing-ball";
@import "pixel-loader";
@import "square-box";
@import "circle-loader";
@import "jumping-dots-loader";
```

Look for the file that cannot be resolved by the module in charge (Look for the error file). with *ctrl + click* ... and comment one by one until you see which of them you did not read, when you found them: you can, **comment** on them, Or **delete** them. They are preloaders, I did not need them.

> /* @import "colored-balls"; */

> /* @import "pixel-loader"; */

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I have recently updated Node.js to latest version & the dependencies for the some of the projects were not rebuilt. So, I deleted existing dependencies & rebuilt them freshly. Then the error was gone.

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Answer (score 2):

Me I resolved the problem by installing resolve-url-loader component as below:

Install
**via npm**

npm install resolve-url-loader --save-dev

**via yarn**

yarn add resolve-url-loader --dev

Answer (score 1):

Checkout git repo with :

```
[core]
    autocrlf = false
```

Because Windows CRLF are not supported by resolve-url-loader, using node-sass but Options not available to setup with Create-React-App. See https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2756