# CSS error source-map information is not available at URL() declaration (found orphan CR, try removeCR option)

Tags: webpack, css-loader, sass-loader, postcss-loader, resolve-url-loader

I am having a problem when I execute NPM start in my project.
I get this error message:

```
./src/assets/base.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/assets/base.scss)
Error: resolve-url-loader: CSS error
  source-map information is not available at url() declaration (found orphan CR, try removeCR option)
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

There can be multiple reasons for this problem, I will give 3 possible solutions please try all of them

1. try updating the `index.js` present in `node_modules\resolve-url-loader`. So here
   under the `var options`

```js
var options = Object.assign({
      sourceMap: loader.sourceMap,
      engine: 'postcss',
      silent: false,
      absolute: false,
      keepQuery: false,
      **
      removeCR: false-- > make this "true" ** ,
      root: false,
      debug: false,
      join: joinFn.defaultJoin
    }
```

then restart your app

2. Next solution is to change end of line sequence to LF
   [See screenshot below to know how it is done in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWe2R.jpg)
3. Check Your CSS files by commenting them one by one and running your code to find the file with the bug. Check all import statements and also the web links in your CSS file.

P.S. This is my first answer so please go easy on me :p
for more reference to what I wrote you can also visit this link -> [For more details you can also refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58649677/node-error-resolve-url-loader-css-error)

Answer (score 15):

1. go to node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js
2. find removeCR option (in my case it was at line 53)
3. change it from "false" to "true"
4. restart your app

Comment: It worked for me, after you make the changes restart the app to see the changes

Comment: in react the location of this file is node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\resolve-url-loader\index.js

Comment: this is a temporary solution

Answer (score 13):

Open the file *.css and select end of line sequense to LF (in my case I have change from CRLF to LF) in IDE.

Comment: Windows have CRLF by default. Editors in windows also do have CRLF by default. I don't think this is a proper solution. CRLF, CR, LF should not matter. They are all new lines

Answer (score 9):

Switch from "CRLF" to "LF" (or vice versa) in your IDE (Visual Studio Code in my case)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Makes a lot of sense.

Comment: But what if we have lots of files like this? Changing them one by one is impossible

Answer (score 4):

Try changing `engine: 'postcss'` in node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js to `engine: 'rework'`, hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I just lost 17h and weekend on this issue.

Simple solution :

Change all  url(..) to new URL(...) inside scss files

Deeper explanation:

Webpack 5 expects new URL(...) declaration, for some reason url leaves CR at the end of the declaration.
It can also be solved by extending webpack configuration adding resolve-url-loader with removeCR:true option

```
  {
//         loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
//         options: {
//           removeCR:true
//         }
//       },
```

but keep in mind that when you target entire scss file with

```
test: /\.(s*)css$/,
```

this will disable built in css support like in next.js and you will need to declare all loaders in webpack manually (going from bottom to top, bottom one being first to call)

Comment: Changing all url(...) to URL(...) has magically fixed it for me.

Comment: This must be selected as answer.

Comment: I guess this is related to this: https://webpack.js.org/blog/2020-10-10-webpack-5-release/#asset-modules

Comment: This is so weird. I am on webpack 4 and tried to upgrade a load of google font files to variable fonts. URL to uppercase worked for all of them except one font, which seemed to want url in the traditional lowercase. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having this issue, I found a permanent solution for this.

You can use .gitattributes to prevent the file from being converted to CRLF.

A .gitattributes file can look like this

```
*.vcproj    eol=crlf
*.sh        eol=lf
```

add

```
*.scss eol=lf
```

This setting forces Git to normalize line endings to LF on checkin and prevents conversion to CRLF when the file is checked out.

Just commit the .gitattributes file and your file will be checkout out on every system with LF line ending.