# Scss error: ./src/routes/styles/home.scss -> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js):

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

Just added a scss file, I tried installing sass but that did not work. Have a feeling downgrading will work but I really dont want to considering all other packages are working with node 18.

The Full Error looks like:

```
Compiled with problems:


ERROR in ./src/routes/styles/home.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[4]!./src/routes/styles/home.scss)

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module './lib/value-processor'
Require stack:
- /home/ed-tee/Documents/Code/profile2/node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js
- /home/ed-tee/Documents/Code/profile2/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
- /home/ed-tee/Documents/Code/profile2/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
- /home/ed-tee/Documents/Code/profile2/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js
- /home/ed-tee/Documents/Code/profile2/node_modules/webpack-manifest-plugin/dist/index.js
- /home/ed-tee/Documents/Code/profile2/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
- /home/ed-tee/Documents/Code/profile2/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ed-tee/Documents/Code/profile2/node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js:16:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
```

I tried installing sass

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I used resolve-url-loader and it worked,

link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url-loader

I also tried some of the solutions on: [Node Error: resolve-url-loader: CSS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58649677/node-error-resolve-url-loader-css-error)

they didnt work but still could be helpful for others.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).